# Soomla - IAP - unity 3D - loading

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I have an issue with unity3D soomla plugin, I setup new store on soomla website, export package and import it to unity project, everything looks fine. But when Im trying to enter to shop the loading indicator shows up and loading forever :-/

Thx.

Comment: Can you add the Unity build log ? Is it Android or iOS ?

Answer (score 2):

haha, i had the same issue this weekend.

Two things happened, not sure what fixed it so im gonna list both,

the soomla store is synced every 12 hours so it might be because i waited so long that it worked, secondly.

When building to Android do not use Build and run, just "build" unity has build it a quick unnoticeable process kicks in basically, unity deploys it to your device before the java assemblies are incorporated from soomla to your package. so just "build" the apk to a folder.

after Unity3d has finished building the package, go to cmd and type in
adb install c:\mygame.apk
and wait,
of course change the path in the example above to point to your new build.

hope that helped.